# How to extract certain divs out of a webpage

Tags: php, html, extract

I want to curl a specific site and extract certains divs out of it to use its contents. The divs that i want to extract do have the same class but to make things even worse these divs are nested...

The idea of using regex is givin me headache. Is there a nicer way to pull this off ?

Best regards

Comment: You're correct that regex is a bad idea for parsing any tree-based text structure. The type of thing you're looking for would be a PHP-based HTML parsing library. (*Which* one to use would likely be an opinion-based question)

Comment: I'd start with [DOM Document](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: here is DOM parser library: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

You should try the PHP Simple DOM Parser: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

With it you can get all elements with a certain class:

```
$ret = $html->find('.foo');
```

Look at the documentation, there is a lot possible!